# JavaFX cover and uncover Button text in a Button field

Tags: java, button, javafx, minesweeper

Okay, so when initializing the playboard for Minesweeper, my code iterates through all the buttons created in the pane and sets the text to either an X for bomb or a number (indicating how many bombs are neighbors). If it's neither it does nothing. But now I wonder how to hide that text when initializing the game so that it can be uncovered and later recovered by clicking the mouse?

[image]

Here's the iteration logic:

```
//iterate through rows and columns to fill board with random bombs
for (int y = 0; y < model.Y_FIELDS; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < model.X_FIELDS; x++) {
        Field field = new Field(x, y, Math.random() < 0.2, model);
        model.array[x][y] = field;
        root.getChildren().add(field);

    }
}

for (int y = 0; y < model.Y_FIELDS; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < model.X_FIELDS; x++) {
        Field field = model.array[x][y];

        if (field.isBomb())
            continue;

        long number = field.getSurrounding().stream().filter(f -> f.isBomb()).count();

        if (number > 0)
            field.board.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }
}
```

I would like them to be blank at first. Where do I put `setText("")`? In a left mouse click event I want to uncover them. That would look something like `if(leftmouseclick)` then `set.Visible` or something like that...

Comment: I have to agree with @fabian. You should not use your buttons to store data. You should have an array like he suggest. I would make my buttons' IDs correspond to the array indexes. I created a game very similar to mine sweep. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example the [`PseudoClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) API to change the CSS pseudo state of your `Button`s between "revealed" and "unrevealed".

You need to define a CSS pseudo class like:

```
.button:unrevealed { -fx-text-fill: transparent; }
```

which will represent the button when it was not pressed yet and makes the text of the `Button` invisible.

And you have to define the JavaFX `PseudoClass` like:

```
PseudoClass unrevealedPseudo = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unrevealed");
```

Then to use it:

```
Button button = new Button("X");
button.pseudoClassStateChanged(unrevealedPseudo, true);

button.setOnAction(e -> button.pseudoClassStateChanged(unrevealedPseudo, false));
```

In the snippet the `Button` is set to be "unrevealed" when it is created, then on press leaves that state, therefore the `-fx-text-fill` property will be changed back to the default one.

If you apply the same creation logic for all of your buttons, it does not matter what the initial text of them, as it is hidden until it is not revealed (by button press or by programatically changing it).

**Note1:** You can use the same API to define more pseudo-classes which will be handy if you for example want to set a "flag" on the button on right click, as you can simply use these CSS classes to define how the buttons should look like in the different states.

**Note2:** If you have a backend, that stores the state of each field (revealed, flagged, unrevealed) for example using a property, in the frontend while creating a separate `Button` for each element of the domain model, you can simply check for the update of the state property of the element in the model, and you can simply put the `Button` into the correct pseudo class. It is much more elegant then changing it on e.g. button click.

**An example with the approach in Note2:**

*Model:*

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class MineSweeperField {
    public enum State {
        UNREVEALED, REVEALED, FLAGGED
    };

    private ObjectProperty<State> state = new SimpleObjectProperty<State>(State.UNREVEALED);

    public ObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() {
        return state;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return stateProperty().get();
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        stateProperty().set(state);
    }
}
```

*Button:*

```
import application.MineSweeperField.State;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class MineSweepButton extends Button {

    static PseudoClass unrevealedPseudo = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unrevealed");
    static PseudoClass revealedPseudo = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("revealed");
    static PseudoClass flaggedPseudo = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flagged");

    public MineSweepButton(MineSweeperField field) {

        this.getStyleClass().add("minesweep-button");

        this.pseudoClassStateChanged(unrevealedPseudo, true);

        field.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> changePseudoClass(newVal));
        changePseudoClass(field.getState());
    }

    private void changePseudoClass(State state) {
        this.pseudoClassStateChanged(unrevealedPseudo, false);
        this.pseudoClassStateChanged(revealedPseudo, false);
        this.pseudoClassStateChanged(flaggedPseudo, false);

        switch (state) {
        case FLAGGED:
            this.pseudoClassStateChanged(flaggedPseudo, true);
            break;
        case REVEALED:
            this.pseudoClassStateChanged(revealedPseudo, true);
            break;
        case UNREVEALED:
            this.pseudoClassStateChanged(unrevealedPseudo, true);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*CSS:*

```
.minesweep-button:unrevealed { -fx-text-fill: transparent; }
.minesweep-button:revealed { -fx-text-fill: black; }
.minesweep-button:flagged { -fx-text-fill: orange; }
```

*Usage:*

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

MineSweeperField field = new MineSweeperField();
MineSweepButton msButton = new MineSweepButton(field);
msButton.setText("5");

Button reveal = new Button("Reveal");
Button unreveal = new Button("Unreveal");
Button flag = new Button("Flag");

root.setTop(new VBox(msButton, new HBox(reveal, unreveal, flag)));
reveal.setOnAction(e -> field.setState(State.REVEALED));
unreveal.setOnAction(e -> field.setState(State.UNREVEALED));
flag.setOnAction(e -> field.setState(State.FLAGGED));
```

*And the output:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just don't set the text before the button is clicked. If you store the `Button`s in a `GridPane`, the row and column indices are stored in the `Button`s anyways. The mines could simply be stored in a `boolean[][]` array and looked up based on the indices. BTW: I recommend using `ToggleButton`s, since they already provide a selected and a unselected state, which could be used to represent nodes already uncovered.

```
private static boolean checkMine(boolean[][] mines, int row, int column) {
    return row >= 0 && column >= 0 && row < mines.length && column < mines[row].length && mines[row][column];
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane field = new GridPane();

    boolean[][] mines = new boolean[][]{
        new boolean[]{false, false, false},
        new boolean[]{false, true, false},
        new boolean[]{false, false, false}
    };

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = event -> {
        ToggleButton source = (ToggleButton) event.getSource();

        // find column/row indices in GridPane
        Integer row = GridPane.getRowIndex(source);
        Integer column = GridPane.getColumnIndex(source);
        int r = row == null ? 0 : row;
        int c = column == null ? 0 : column;

        boolean mine = mines[r][c];

        if (mine) {
            source.setText("X");
            System.out.println("you loose");
            // TODO: Represent lost state in GUI
        } else {
            int mineCount = 0;

            // count surrounding mines
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
                for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                    if (checkMine(mines, r + i, c + j)) {
                        mineCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (mineCount > 0) {
                source.setText(Integer.toString(mineCount));
            }
        }
        source.setDisable(true);
        // keep activated look
        source.setOpacity(1);
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < mines.length; i++) {
        boolean[] row = mines[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton();
            toggleButton.setPrefSize(30, 30);
            toggleButton.setOnAction(handler);
            field.add(toggleButton, j, i);
        }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(field);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```